# Linux OS without Java

Tags: lubuntu, mint

Currently I use Linux Mint 17.1 I was wondering how would I install it without Java. Or how do I completely remove it.

Does Linux Lite have Java in it by default?

Currently I use LAMP, Office Libre without Base, common browsers, and other common software like Filezilla, Transmission, GIMP, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Most questions about non-official Ubuntu derivatives are classified as *off-topic*. This isn't the correct Stack Exchange site to ask questions about non-official Ubuntu distributions (see the [help/on-topic]. However, it would be on-topic at the [unix.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command remove open jdk

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk*
```